# How to use eloquent one to one with all and get laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relational-database, one-to-one

Here is the code for my categories controller

```
public function index () {
    $categories = Category::get(['id', 'image_id', 'name','slug', 'is_active'])->all();
    return view('admin_pages.categories.categories', compact('categories'));
}
```

I want to get image path from the categories_images table using image_id field. I have used the relationship in the categories model as this

```
public function image () {
    return $this->hasOne('App\CategoryImage');
}
```

On the CategoryImage model i have no relationship specified. How can i get the image path in the categories object.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `all()` here. To load relation use [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$categories = Category::with('image')->get();
```

To access image you should itarate over collection of categories and then use `->image` relation:

```
$category->image->url;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. But what if i just want to return image path only an not the complete object.
`code`
    public function image () {
         return $this->hasOne('App\CategoryImage');
    }
`code`

Comment: Try to add `select()` like `return $this->hasOne('App\CategoryImage')->select('image_path');`

Comment: Using Select('path') is not returning anything. Path is a column in the categories_images table. However if i don't use select the whole row gets return including path.